# How to read from an internal TXT file in Unity C# WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have searched Reddit, Youtube, Google and Stackoverflow and i couldn't find the answer/solution to my problem. Thus i am making a post.

I am using Unity to build an application. Within this application i have an internal TXT file which gets read and parsed to different UI Text elements. My system works completely find in the Unity editor though when i build the application as WebGL it doesn't work. The build succeeds but the UI Text elements aren't updated. I suspect the TXT file isn't build with the WebGL build or the WebGL requires a different way to read the TXT file. Can i get some help on what im doing wrong and how to fix this?

```
public void LoadInfoDoc()
{
    if (infoDoc != null)
    {
        infoDocLines = (infoDoc.text.Split('\n'));

        int temp = infoDocLines.Length;

        if (temp == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("The document was loaded but the lines have not been read correctly.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("Loaded text file correctly. File has " + infoDocLines.Length + " entries.");

            for (int i = 0; i < infoDocLines.Length; i++)
            {
                string tempStrHelpNum = infoDocLines[i].Substring(0, cutLength); //tempStr is ussed to save the first 2 letters of each info

                string tempStrFullText = infoDocLines[i].ToString();
                tempStrFullText = tempStrFullText.Remove(0, cutLength);
                tempStrFullText = tempStrFullText.TrimStart();
                int tempInt = i;
                SortHelpInfo(tempStrHelpNum, tempInt, tempStrFullText);

                //PrintLinesDEV(i);
            }              
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Document was not assigned correctly");
    }
}

private void SortHelpInfo(string helpNum, int tempInt, string tempStrFullText)
{
    switch (helpNum)
    {
        case "01.0":     
            helpList01.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "02.0":
            helpList02.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "03.0":
            helpList03.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "04.0":
            helpList04.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "05.0":
            helpList05.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "06.0":
            helpList06.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "07.0":
            helpList07.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "08.0":
            helpList08.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "09.0":
            helpList09.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "10.0":
            helpList10.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "11.0":
            helpList11.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;
            
        case "12.0":
            helpList12.Add(tempStrFullText);
            break;

        case "99.9":
            //Used to allow a gap in the document
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("There was an issue when sorting the info lines. Its for"+ helpNum);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not actually show how you are reading the file.

Comment: @bolkay I've updated the post with more code

Comment: have you tried System.IO.File.ReadAllText to read a text file?

Comment: Can you please provide more informations about infoDoc? Is it created inside the application? Does it exist before? Where is it saved?

Comment: @nka_Zz The infoDoc script is attached to a gameobject which is always active. It runs as soon as the scene is loaded. It works perfectly fine in the editor just not WebGL

Comment: So it sounds like `infoDoc` is a `TextAsset` field? In which folder is it placed? How do you reference it in the Inspector? And do you just assume that the issue is that the file is missing or have you actually **debugged** that?

Comment: @derHugo Yes it is a TextAsset. It is placed in the following folder - https://i.gyazo.com/ea3ea63f5ba1b94f3d201253ccd88ca4.png

As it is a public TextAsset i dragged and dropped the document in the inspector. Though i have now tried to load the document via the resources folder using the following code

private void Awake()
    {
        infoDoc = Resources.Load("Other/WellbeingInfo") as TextAsset;
        LoadInfoDoc();
    }

Still doesnt work :/

Comment: Have you tried not putting it in a `Resources` folder at all?

Comment: @derHugo It is in the resources folder

Comment: Yes I see that ... Again: Have you tried to **not** put it in a Resources folder?

Comment: @derHugo Woops. Sorry i read your comment wrong. It wasn't originally in the resources folder. Original it was in a random folder and i assigned the txt file via the inspector (drag and drop)

Answer (score 0):

When Unity builds your project it does not include every object that is in your project hierarchy. If it would your project would include a lot of unnecessary object and scripts that you don't use in your scene. So if you load an object in a script from a path e.g. a text file, it will not be included, because unity does not check the entire code for loading objects and such.

One way to make sure that your textfile/material/mesh is included is to place it in a [`Resources`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) folder, each object placed in this folder will be also included in your build. Objects in Resource folders can be reached with [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). But including everything in resources folders is not the best choice as every object that is included in this folder will always be loaded when you start your application. This way you can load a lot of unnecessary data into the memory. Another way is to use [`AssetBundles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html), AssetBundles are more flexible and can be loaded at runtime, this way you don't bloat the memory. The Assetbundle can be loaded with [`AssetBundle.LoadFromFile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html) Unity created a [guide](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#) on when and how to use Resources and AssetBundles. I would suggest you take a look at that.

Comment: I have used Resources.Load but it still hasn;t fixed anything. This is the code

private void Awake()
    {
        infoDoc = Resources.Load("Other/WellbeingInfo") as TextAsset;
        LoadInfoDoc();
    }

And here is an image to where my txt file is currently stored - https://i.gyazo.com/ea3ea63f5ba1b94f3d201253ccd88ca4.png

Comment: and the loading via resources works on the editor but not on webGL?

Comment: Yes it does mate. Works fine in the editor but not WebGL

Comment: have you debugged if it fails at loading or if it fails at some other point?

Comment: How would you suggest i do that as i cant see the console when i built it via WebGL

Comment: you can read [Debug.Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-debugging.html) messages in the console